# Reducing excessive Graphviz octagon margins

Tags: graphviz, margins

The Graphviz output of octagon-shaped nodes has huge margins, even we set "margin=0.0,0.0".

Example:

```
digraph G {
  foo [shape=octagon, label="one\ntwo", margin="0.0,0.0"];
}
```

Produces:

[image: digraph G]

I want to have smaller margins than those, with the letter edges close to the diagonal edges of octagon. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple answer: not easily.  you are encountering two issues:

- default node width & height are a bit bigger than you want (easy to fix)
- Graphviz's suboptimal algorithm that sizes polygons

more complex: here is an improvement, but it is a (repeatable) kludge.  It does graph layout & octagon sizing using a small font, then resets the fontsize to correct (desired) value.  It uses **gvpr** (http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpr.1.pdf) and `neato -n2` (http://www.graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithCoords)

1. give all your octagon nodes an explicit fontsize that is 3 points smaller that you actually want.  Since default fontsize is 14 (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/fontsize/), try [fontsize=11]
2. run this pipeline to layout your graph, and then reset the fontsize:

```
dot myfile.gv |
gvpr -c 'N[shape=="octagon"]{$.fixedsize="true"; $.fontsize=$.fontsize + 3;}' | neato -n2 -Tpng >myfile.png
```

A modified version of "one two" (with reduced height & width):

```
digraph G {
  foo [fontsize=11 height=.4 width=.6 fixedsize=true shape=octagon label="one\ntwo"]
}
```

Gives:
[image]

And a larger input file:

```
graph Y{
rankdir=LR
label="simple octagon"
aeiou
onemore [shape=rect]
node[fontsize=11]
foo1 [shape=octagon, label="ab\na"]
foo3 [shape=octagon, label="abcd\nabc"]
foo5 [shape=octagon, label="abcdef\nabcde"]
foo7 [shape=octagon, label="abcdefgh\nabcdefg"]
foo9 [shape=octagon, label="abcdefghij\nabcdefghi"]
foo11 [shape=octagon, label="abcdefghijkl\nabcdefghijk"]
foo13 [shape=octagon, label="abcdefghijklmn\nabcdefghijklm"]
foo15 [shape=octagon, label="abcdefghijklmnop\nabcdefghijklmno"]
foo17 [shape=octagon, label="abcdefghijklmnopqr\nabcdefghijklmnopq"]
foo19 [shape=octagon, label="abcdefghijklmnopqrst\nabcdefghijklmnopqrs"]
}
```

Gives:
[image]

Comment: sorry, I dropped a brace in the command string.  fixed above

Comment: Do you happen to know what the graphviz maintainers think about this situation? Is a bug filed about it? You seem to be quite the graphviz expert...

Comment: On a quick look, I saw no existing issues.  Here is the URL for Graphviz issues.  While not a developer, I do like to help.

Comment: Good grief!  Here is URL:  https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues

Comment: Filed [this bug](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/2309).